# Problem with tag anchor and href, only HTML

Tags: html, tags, href, anchor

I don't know wath's wrong whit this code.
When I click on anchor tag with href to google, I remain in the file path.
This is the URL before I click:

> ../Yellow_Pipeline_GAS/Single_Page_PipeLine/HTML/index_pipe_line.html?_ijt=29qbqm70jetpqbn6ivus30bn7s

This is the URL after I click:

> ../Yellow_Pipeline_GAS/Single_Page_PipeLine/HTML/www.google.com

HTML:

```
<div class="logoGroup_conguagli-center dropdown">
        <p>ZERO CONGUALI E STIME</p>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hello World!</a><br>
            <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br>
            <a href="#">Hello World!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
  .logoGroup_conguagli-center {
            top: -2px;
            left: 430px;
            animation-name: opaco;
            animation-duration: 1.5s;
            width: 210px;

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.2);
        padding: 12px 16px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 5px;
        animation-name: pannel;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `href="http://www.google.com"`. It will work for you.